# What is the best practice to have a variable which lives for application lifetime in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, api

I am developing a web service 'A' using Node.js, which communicate with an another service 'B'. A needs to get an access token from B at the beginning, and it needs to refresh it when the token expires.

I am not very familiar with Node.js, I need to store access token and refresh token comes from B and refresh them time to time, but I am not sure if there are global variables to do this. For example, in Flask I would have kept my tokens in app['tokens'] and could be update it.

Basically what I want to do is to have a B class and a global object of B, B will have accessToken and refreshToken fields, obj.sendRequest({requestInfo}) will send a request to B service by checking expiration time of tokens and refresh them if necessary.

What is the best practice to overcome such a problem in Node.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question I don't see if you are using TypeScript or not. I highly recommend it, but it is not required. I will give you my answer with a TypeScript example because it is easier to read and understand (I think). Adapting it to pure JS should be easy.

```
class ApiService {
  private accessToken?: string
  private accessTokenExpires?: Date
  private async getAccessToken(): Promise<void> {
    const apiResult = await GET_TOKEN_FROM_API
    this.accessToken = apiResult.access_token
    this.accessTokenExpires = apiResult.access_token_expires
  }

  public async GetItem(id: string): Promise<Item> {
    if (!this.accessToken || this.accessTokenExpires < new Date()) {
      await this.getAccessToken()
    }

    return GET_ITEM_FROM_API
  }
}

export let itemService = new ItemService()
export function mockitemService(mock: any) {
  itemService = mock
}
```

at the place where you want to use the class you can

```
import { itemService } from './services/item'
const item = itemService.getItem('123')
```

Using ServiceClasses like this makes easier to maintain the code later or to write tests with mocked data sources.